# Is JFrog Xray is available for Free Edition?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

I have Free edition of JFrog Artifactory and tried installing Jfrog Xray, i can see Xray service is up and running but i cannot see any difference in Artifactory UI (Xray tab).

Can anyone pls mention are you using Free edition of Xray or Xray will only comes up with Paid version of Artifactory?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends on whether you are using the Self-hosted instance or the SaaS.

As you can see in the JFrog documentation (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Xray) on Xray (at the top right corner - Subscription levels), Xray is only available for Pro-X and above licenses for a self-hosted instance.

However, if you are using the SaaS - it should be available for the free version as well.

Comment: Usually it’s available on free tier, but visible on UI if you choose at the beginning that you are interested with security and vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

it’s available on free tier, but visible on UI if you choose at the beginning that you are interested with security and vulnerabilities.

Another way to make it visible on the UI is to upload a package / image and then inside the package details you should have a “Security” tab where there you will have a banner to enable xray in the UI